# Child process flamegraphs

Tags: process, profiling

Are there any tools that will give me a flamegraph of child process execution. For example if I run `make` I would see all of the `gcc` invokations in a nice tree with their start and end times.

The closest thing I could find is [Snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) but it is very unclear about exactly what it does. It also uses `LD_PRELOAD` interception which is not 100% reliable. (And I don't think it actually generates any visualisations.)